# Lenovo G570 restarts randomly

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, reboot, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo G570 began to randomly restart once or twice a day about two weeks ago. It stopped for a few days and then started doing it again. I don't get a BSoD, it just restarts and gives me the screen where you choose whether to start Windows in safe mode or not.

I have no idea what's causing this. I added an additional 2GB of RAM almost 2 months ago and ran Memtest then. There weren't any issues, and the restarts only started happening recently so I don't think it's RAM related. I thought it might be a power issue as I was running the laptop on just the adapter without the battery, but I've since then been running it with both inserted and it still happens. I've kind of run out of ideas other than starting to worry it's either a CPU or motherboard issue, so any help would be appreciated.